# setting File Properties does not work

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive, permissions

I recently got my first RasPi and once I've set it up I attached an external Harddrive to download files onto.

When I checked the Permissions in File Properties I noticed that it was set to:

> Owner: pi
>   Group: pi
>   Access Control
>   View Content: Only owner
>   Change Content: Only owner
>   Access Content: Only owner

I changed each one to Anyone and clicked OK. When I checked back, it was set back to "Only owner".

I switched to Terminal and `cd /media/pi/DISC-NAME` to the drive's location where I run the following:

```
ls -l
```

This gave me the output `drwx------` on all folders on the drive. My next commands:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R Downloads
ls -l
```

I did not get any output on the `chmod` command and `ls -l` returned the same `drwx------` as before.

Is there something I did not see or not considered. I appreciate any advise. Thanks!